# Configure Server Setting Issue in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, lcds

I am trying to Configure Server side Code in  Flash Builder 4.5.I am Using LCDS 2.6.1.By clicking on validate configuration button I got message on top Only Life Cycle DataService 2.6 and higher are supported.I am using 2.6.1.still not able to figure out the issue.Please help.

Comment: Flex 4.5.1 is an SDK an does not have a visual element to it where you would click any buttons or configure LifeCycle.  Did you mean Flash Builder 4.5.1?  Where do you click the validate configuration button?  Can you post a screenshot of the message?

Answer (score 0):

This version of LCDS works with Action Script 3.x so make sure your flex SDK is 3.5 in Flash Builder 4.X. Also make sure you have included the correct LCDS JAR files in your flex project.

Comment: I am new to Flash Builder and Flex programming. I am also facing similar issue. I selected 3.5 SDK for my project. But no luck. How do I make sure what version of Action script is installed on my Flash Builder 4.X version?

Comment: Have not used flash builder for two years, but I think you just need to right click your project in the project navigator and look at the properties. There should be a specific section for action script or whatever they are calling it these days.